# How to extract data from feed back in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php

I want to make a feedback system. Where user types some words like "bad, good, very good, excellent etc". And the rating of my product become according to the user given feedback. Three-star or four-star etc.

Comment: we help you if you have a problem, what is the problem?  what where is  your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to create a form and a button to pass the inputs. To get a precise and accurate evaluation (stars in your case) i'd recomment not using inputtype=text but rather Radiobuttons. then pass the Result to the database.

You can then retrieve the DB entries and evaluate those.

Here something to readup on
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: i know how to send data with php. i don't know your concept??